# Dask array operation on chunks with no return

Tags: python, dask

I have a dask array of dimension `(C, Y, X)` (for instance, `(100, 50000, 50000)`).

I want to perform an operation on each chunk that will add some value to a small numpy array, that we will call `x`. Note that the operation on each chunk doesn't need to return any value, it will just update one row of `x`.

I have the current implementation below (pseudo-code) that works but is quite ugly and seems to use too much memory (I have some memory errors sometimes). I was wondering if there is a better solution for this?

```py
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

image = ... # dask array of shape (C, Y, X)
x = np.zeros(100, 20)

def func(chunk, block_info=None):
    row_index = ... # the coordinates of the chunk is needed to get the row index that we will update
    new_value = ... # here, I perform an operation on my chunk
    x[row_index] += new_value
    return da.zeros_like(chunk) # I have to return something that has the shape of the chunk

image = image.rechunk({0: -1}) # I don't want chunks on the channel axis (each chunk is still quite light in term of RAM)
image.map_blocks(func).compute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask prefers to be functional rather than operations having side-effects. Your method will still work, but only with the threaded scheduler, because all "workers" will see the same array object. If this limitation is acceptable, you have some options:

- use your current method (np.zeros does not actually allocate any memory, but the final compute() probably does)
- use the argument `chunks=` in map_blocks to return a smaller array, but stay with the array API
- use array .to_delayed() to apply arbitrary functions to each block, where the type of the return value is arbitrary (can be None)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use `.to_delayed` and see if I can improve it

Comment: Oh but I realized, I can't get `block_info` with `.to_delayed`, right? Unfortunately, I need the coordinates of the chunks, because I will perform some shapely operations on it. So I don't see a better solution yet...

Comment: In that case, you need option 2 from the list. Alternatively, the list of delayed objects is is a particular order, so you can infer where each one fits in the whole, with a little manual code.